# Build error in Visual studio "Duplicate string index signature" in angular2 quickstarts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, typescript, angular, visual-studio-2015

If have cloned the `angular2 rc4 quickstarts` and tried to run this in visual studio. If I build the solution I got a couple of errors like this:
Build:Duplicate string index signature. ..\typings\globals\jasmine\index.d.ts

Running the app anyway so the angular part works but I have notice that there is no dll created. What I do wrong?

I use `VS 2015 Update 2` and `Angular2 RC4` and `Typescript` is

```
$ tsc -v
Version 1.8.10
```

**UPDATE**
I have notice that also if I run tsc I have the same errors. So it look likes that is not a Visual Studio problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try removing the typings folder and reinstall with "typings install"?

Comment: yeah great this solved my problem. why the simplest solution is sometimes so far away :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall typings was the solution for me. Thanks to Thennarasan